# Istio Origin Authentication Using JWT does not work

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, policy, istio

I’ve been applying Authentication Policy to my testing service using JWT. I have followed [this guide](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication) and it did work as expected. But, when I tried to using a different pod image, it did not work even though almost everything is the same.

Is there anyone facing this issue? or know the reason why it did not work in my case?

Thank you very much!

---

These are my configuration files:

### Deployment

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hostname
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hostname
      version: v1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hostname
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rstarmer/hostname:v1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: hostname
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
```

### Service

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: hostname
  name: hostname
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8001
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: hostname
```

### Gateway

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hostname-gateway
  namespace: foo
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
```

### VirtualService

```
---
piVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hostname-vs
  namespace: foo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - hostname-gateway
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8001
        host: hostname.foo.svc.cluster.local
```

### Policy

```
---
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: "jwt-example"
  namespace: foo
spec:
  targets:
  - name: hostname
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "testing@secure.istio.io"
      jwksUri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/istio/istio/release-1.0/security/tools/jwt/samples/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Comment: You need to provide more details. Exactly what have you changed, was is only image? What were the differences, as you said they are almost the same. Can you post logs from the not working one?

Comment: Hi @Crou, 
Thanks for replying!
The differences are the services port (e.g using 8001 versus 8000) and the pod port (80 versus 8000). I'm using Kubernetes 1.13 and Istio 1.05. The problem is that I could still connect to the service via Istio Ingress Gateway on node port 31380 even I applied Origin Authentication JWT (e.g returned 200 status code). But it would work as expected if I only updated VirtualService pointing to port 8000 (httpin service) and updated "targets" in Policy to point to "httpbin". So I'm not sure what I did wrong,I don't think it was caused by the image I'm using,right?

Comment: @Crou, you could run the yaml you will see, you still can connect to that service even applying the policy.

Comment: You said, you changed the image. What image are you using now?

Comment: @SangNguyen Hey  ! Have you find any solution to your problem ? I got the exact same question...

Comment: @SangNguyen Found your answer on the istio forum. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As stated by OP on the [Istio forums](https://discuss.istio.io/t/jwt-policy-does-not-take-affect/141/12) you need to respect the [naming convention](https://istio.io/help/faq/traffic-management/?&_ga=2.241172546.1948819398.1556528753-469248409.1540283226#naming-port-convention) for the port name of your service.
It can either be **"http"** or **"http2"**.

> For instance this is valid

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: somename
  namespace: auth
spec:
  selector:
    app: someapp
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
    name: http
```

---

> And this is not

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: somename
  namespace: auth
spec:
  selector:
    app: someapp
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 3000
```

Not specifying a name for the port is not valid.