# Istio JWT authentication passes traffic without token

Tags: kubernetes, jwt, istio

**Background:**

There was a similar question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140994/istio-origin-authentication-using-jwt-does-not-work) but it didn't offer a solution to my issue.

I have deployed an application which is working as expected to my Istio Cluster.  I wanted to enable JWT authentication, so adapting the instructions [Here](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authn-policy/#end-user-authentication) to my use-case.

**ingressgateway:**

I first applied the following policy to the istio-ingressgateway.  This worked and any traffic sent without a JWT token was blocked.

```
kubectl apply -n istio-system -f mypolicy.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: core-api-policy
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  targets:
  - name: istio-ingressgateway
    ports:
    - number: 80
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_pa9vj7sbL"
      jwksUri: "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_pa9vj7sbL/.well-known/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Once that worked I deleted this policy and installed a new policy for my service.

```
kubectl delete -n istio-system -f mypolicy.yaml
```

**service/core-api-service:**

After editing the above policy, changing the namespace and target as below, I reapplied the policy to the correct namespace.

Policy:

```
kubectl apply -n solarmori -f mypolicy.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Policy
metadata:
  name: core-api-policy
  namespace: solarmori
spec:
  targets:
  - name: core-api-service
    ports:
    - number: 80
  origins:
  - jwt:
      issuer: "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_pa9vj7sbL"
      jwksUri: "https://cognito-idp.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ap-northeast-1_pa9vj7sbL/.well-known/jwks.json"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: core-api-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: api-svc-port
    targetPort: api-app-port
  selector:
    app: core-api-app
```

The outcome of this action didn't appear to change anything in processing of traffic. I was still able to reach my service even though I did not provide a JWT.

I checked the istio-proxy of my service deployment and there was no creation of a `local_jwks` in the logs as described [Here](https://istio.io/help/ops/security/end-user-auth/).

```
[procyclinsur@P-428 istio]$ kubectl logs -n solarmori core-api-app-5dd9666777-qhf5v -c istio-proxy | grep local_jwks
[procyclinsur@P-428 istio]$
```

If anyone knows where I am going wrong I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a Service to be part of Istio's service mesh you need to fulfill some requirements as shown in the official [docs](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/spec-requirements/).

In your case, the service port name needs to be updated to:
 `<protocol>[-<suffix>]` with the `<protocol>` as either:

- grpc
- http
- http2
- https
- mongo
- mysql
- redis
- tcp
- tls
- udp

At that point requests forwarded to the service will go through the service mesh; Currently, requests are resolved by Kubernetes networking.

Comment: wow... you would think a note to check this would be in the troubleshooting section... spent 2 days trying to get this working! thanks!!